# How to configure a local network for 'no internet'

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I have recently built a small server that acts as a wireless access point.  Unfortunately, the server has no way of accessing the internet due to technical constraints.

When I use a smartphone (both iOS and Android) to connect to the server, it loses access to the internet, even though internet is available through my cell service.

Is there a way to configure my server in such a way that my smartphone will understand there is no internet available on this network?  My goal is to be able to have my phone connect to both the server for local file sharing and cellular for internet at the same time

Comment: Can you provide more details on your server? What OS is it running, what hardware it has and particularly the "acts as a wireless access point" part? Have you tried using the "wifi hotspot" feature on your android phone to share internet with the rest of the network?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are going to be able to do that.  When the phone connects to Wi-Fi it shuts off its 3G/4G radio.  And when the phone disconnects from Wi-Fi it turns on its 3G/4G radio.  The two are never active at the same time.  So if there actually is some way to make both active, then it is going to be something in the phone settings, rather than your server's settings.